# Laravel trailing slash connects to GET instead of POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a POST route setup called user/connect which points to the relevant controller function ( which expects post varialbles), but adding a trailing slash e.g. user/connect/ redirects it to GET thus returning "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

I am unable to remove the forward slash ( as the consuming app is sending it and i have no control ) . Any pointers on how i could get the route with the trailing slash to also point to my POST route ?

Comment: This is most probably an webserver redirect rule issue.

Comment: nope, there is only 1 route set, checked with php artisan route:list

Comment: nah it's fine. glad i could help.

Comment: Why don't you write a route something like Route::post('/user/connect/{id?}', ... );

Answer (score 0):

You should use ‘php artisan list:route’ to find a conflicting route. Laravel will not alter the HTTP method. The app could also be wrong so some investigation is needed there as well.

Comment: checked that as well, there is only one route:

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using user3532758 comment, seems that if i remove the following from the public/.htaccess it fixes it, but i am not sure if it opens up another security hole so checking that as well

removing the following fixes it:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Removing is not the answer though. You need to handle the trailing slash.